# Strange closesocket() behavior

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, network-programming, winsock

I have noticed a strange behavior when calling `closesocket()`. If I create a thread that calls `recv()`, then `closesocket()` would send an `RST` packet to the other side. However, if I do not create a receive thread then `closesocket()` would perform a graceful disconnection (4-way handshake).

The following code will cause `closesocket()` to send an `RST` packet:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <process.h>

unsigned int __stdcall thread(void *s)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    recv((SOCKET)s, buffer, 1024, 0);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("173.194.116.18");
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    connect(s, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    // Start thread
    _beginthreadex(0, 0, thread, (void*)s, 0, 0);
    Sleep(1000); // give thread some time to start

    // RST packet will be sent (if you remove the receive thread then a graceful disconnection will be performed)
    closesocket(s);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** I am using blocking sockets.

Comment: Is it possible that your buffer isn't large enough to read the entire response in one read? I am guessing you have  a partial read.

Comment: [closesocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582.aspx): *"A Winsock client must never issue **closesocket** on* s *concurrently with another Winsock function call."*

Comment: @IInspectable So I need to make sure that no other Winsock function is using `s` when I call `closesocket()`?

Comment: @user4572253 That's right.

Comment: @IInspectable: Despite what the doc says, when dealing with multi-threaded blocking sockets, calling `closesocket()` from another thread is the only way to abort a blocking `send/recv()` in progress.  Unless you use `setsockopt()` to specify sending/reading timeouts.  And frankly, I have been doing WinSock programming for well over a decade and have NEVER seen that comment in the doc, or in any WinSock tutorials, and have never had any problems with closing blocking sockets across thread boundaries.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No it isn't. You can shutdown the socket for input. The `recv()` will unblock and return zero and everybody will be happy.

Comment: The RST is caused by the act of closing the socket *when there is unread pending data*, not merely by calling it while `recv()` is blocking.

Comment: @EJP I have tried closing the socket when there is no pending data and a thread is blocking on `recv()`, and an RST has been sent. I have also tried to close the socket when there is no pending data and no thread is blocking on `recv()` and a FIN has been sent. So I don't think that your statement is correct.

Answer (score 1):

if the
client sends more than one byte,  server will read the first byte and call close with data in its receive queue,causing a RST to be sent to the client. The client will be blocked on a call to recv( ) waiting the response from the
server. Upon receiving the RST, DieWithError( ) reports the problem  Connection reset by peer.
So shutdown can be used  before calling close.
I hope this article will help you related RST http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/TCPRST.pdf

Comment: Please provide context for the link you posted (see [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)). If the resource disappears, the answer no longer provides any value.

Comment: If the client sends more than one byte the server will unblock and almost certainly read them all at the same time.