# How to exit a blocking recv() call?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, network-programming, winsock

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941572/strange-closesocket-behavior?noredirect=1#comment46164827_28941572), when you call `closesocket()` on a socket that `recv()` is already using, then an `RST` packet will be sent to the other side instead of performing  a graceful disconnection (4-way handshake).

But I wish to perform a graceful disconnection, so I need to exit `recv()` before calling `closesocket()`.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You *can't* call `closesocket` on a socket that `recv` is already using. Try to write code to do it, it's pretty much impossible. You would need some way to know that the `recv` had already accessed the socket using some kind of thread context inspection. Your code will inevitably have race conditions in which terrible things can happen.

Comment: "when you call closesocket() on a socket that recv() is already using, then an RST packet will be sent to the other side" This really is not true. The RST is caused by the act of closing the socket when there is unread pending data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `shutdown()` the socket for input. The `recv()` will unblock and return zero and everybody will be happy.

Comment: This does not always work, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737707/exit-a-blocking-recv-call with the right server (that does not accept input). This and David Schwartz comment (a deeper variation of "A Winsock client must never issue closesocket on s concurrently with another Winsock function call.") make me feel that the only solution when shutdown does not work is ... non blocking sockets.

Comment: It also does not work if, after connection, a cable is unplugged in a router, effectively cutting the communication, but without immediate effect for the TCP/IP connection (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085676/tcp-socket-no-connection-timeout).

Comment: @Liviu There is nothing in this answer about calling `closesocket()`, and there is nothing in the links you cite that confirm your claim that shutting down a socket for input doesn't work when a cable is pulled. It is difficult to see any connection between the two events actually.

Comment: Man, I cannot verify your claims one year later (different job, no router)... But, if the (real network) connection is down (by pulling a cable not directly connected to your computer), your `shutdown` won't unblock anything as the blocking socket does not known that the connection is down and it will wait for some timeout (that can be minutes long: it was 2 minutes maybe, for us)

Comment: "There is nothing in this answer about calling `closesocket()`". It isn't, but I never said it, isn't it? On the other hand, your (so called) anwser won't work in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737707/exit-a-blocking-recv-call. So "How to exit a blocking recv() call?"

Comment: I see now ... you are the "expert" that closed a legitimate question: ["Exit a blocking recv() call"] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737707/exit-a-blocking-recv-call). Have you even bother to test it before saying "Works for everybody else" ? (This site has real troubles, like allowing you to close questions.)

Comment: @Liviu It knows that the connection has been shutdown for input, which unblocks it and causes it to return zero. And you oo videoing irrelevant quote containing `closesockst()`. It's up there in black and white.

Comment: @ user207421 out of this discussion, sorry, please stop mentioning my name

Comment: @Liviu You can't control that. Or the site.

Comment: I've been looking online a lot for ways to abort accept and recv calls (I am being lazy to write/use a proper concurrent/scalable/async design but trying to remain efficient by avoiding polling/timeout of any kind). I was happy to find that recv could be aborted by shutdown thinking I am avoiding a nasty racing condition when using closesocket that risks an incorrect socket being passed into recv. Initial tests showed that shutdown works, but after injecting a DLL into another process and connecting from there, recv was not aborted by shutdown as expected, only closesocket() managed to do it:(

Comment: Is there really no way to achieve this with closesocket but eliminate the racing condition? My thinking is set the socket to INVALID_SOCKET first, wait 100ms or so, then issue a closesocket on the original socket. The window of 100ms or so should be enough for target thread to avoid passing original socket that we have closed. Anyone care to comment?

Comment: Another alternative I've come across which shows promise (not tested) which is to have the listener socket as well as all clients select on their socket plus one shared socket between all of them which we can signal for reading...apparently all threads would wake up.   <goes to test stuff out.......argh sockets in my life....AGAIN?!!!!>

Comment: Just final comment regarding accept() which in my tests could not be aborted by shutdown, but only by closesocket (or if selecting on it plus an additional socket); I've done it by having a dummy client connect prior to signalling for termination - fairly painless but aborting recv's is more important at the moment, and I think the above solution of having a dummy socket for listener and all clients to select on would be one solution for aborting both calls, if it works

Answer (score 0):

The real issue here is that a sure kill, terminatethread(), has all kinds of warnings on it about bad effects of its use. I have been using this method to exit an recv(). The windows docs says "you must know what the thread is doing before applying terminatethread", well, we know what it is doing, its in recv(). The question is not what the THREAD is doing, its what windows kernel is doing.

In the embedded system RTOSes I have done killthread() is doable. Its not EASY, you have to find every single lock and resource owned by the thread and back it out. Only the OS has that kind of information (and power).

Comment: `terminatethread()` is not mentioned in the question. Hard to see why this 'real issue' is relevant.

Comment: `terminatethread` can be used as a last resort (when the previous answer, the accepted "solution", does not work) to stop the thread of a blocking socket.

Comment: The question was (did you read it?) How to exit a blocking recv() call? terminating the calling thread is one way to do that.